# Riemann Integrability of non continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

This is for homework so I'd rather not have answers but I would appreciate suggestions on where to go with this.

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x^2 &\text{ for }x\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\\
 0 &\text{ for }x\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$
(i) Show that $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$

(ii) If $0\le\xi<\zeta\le1$ show that $$\bigg(\frac{\zeta+\xi}{2}\bigg)^2(\zeta-\xi)\ge\frac{1}{4}(\zeta^3-\xi^3)$$

(iii) Use the inequality in (ii) to show that $f\notin\mathcal{R}([0,1])$.

Comment: Specifically I am stuck on the last part . . .

Comment: Notice that $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ looks conspicuously different from $[0,1]\backslash\mathbb Q$.  The former is standard correct usage when the meaning is the difference of sets and I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: The lower Riemann Sum is obviously zero since the irrationals are dense.  So the hint is probably to show the upper Riemann Sum is bounded away from zero and so the upper and lower cannot be converging to each other.

Comment: That's about where I am stuck. Not sure how to apply the inequality from the second part.

Comment: It is nor hard to show that $U(f,P) = U(x \mapsto x^2, P)$, so showing that $f$ is not integrable is straightforward. However, it is not clear to me how the other inequality helps...

Comment: What is (ii)?$\,\,$

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have this idea: assume the function is $\mathcal R[0,1]\;$ . For any partition $\;P=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n\;$ of $\;[0,1]\;$ , we have that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f(c_i)|(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\begin{cases}0\;,\;&c_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\cap\left([0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q\right)\\{}\\\sum_\limits{k=1}^nc_i^2(x_i-x_{i-1})\;,\;&c_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\cap\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

But for the lower expression we have

$$c_i^2(x_i-x_{i-1})\ge\left(\frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}2\right)^2(x_i-x_{i-1})\ge\frac14\left(x_i^3-x_{i-1}^3\right)$$

if we choose $\;\frac{x_{i-1}+x_i}2\le c_i\;$ (we can do this as the Riemann sums do not depend on the $\;c_i'$s we choose and because of the assumption) , so that

$$\sum_\limits{k=1}^nc_i^2(x_i-x_{i-1}]\ge\frac14\sum_\limits{k=1}^n(x_i^3-x_{i-1}^3)=\frac14$$

and this shows our assumption is false as the sum depends on the points chosen in the partition's subintervals..

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I actually recently talked to some classmates and we were able to come up with just this.